# Why does `include` behave differently at the top level?

Tags: ruby, class, include, program-entry-point

I used the following hook to check the module that is doing the including when I do `include Foo`:

```
module Foo
  def self.included(includer)
    puts includer
  end
end
```

`Module#include` behaves differently in a module (where it is usually used) vs. at the top level. Inside a module, `self` is the module, which is an instance of `Module`. When I call `include`, the module doing the including is **what `self` is**:

```
module Bar
  puts self   # => Bar
  include Foo # => includer: Bar
end
```

At the top level of a ruby script, `self` is `main`, which is an instance of `Object`. When I call `include` at the top level, the module doing including is `Object`, **the class of what `self` is**:

```
puts self    # => main
include Foo  # => includer: Object
```

Can someone explain why?

The top-level object must be special; If I call `to_s` or `inspect` on it, it just says `main`, but if I create another object with `Object.new` and call `to_s` or `inspect` on it, I get the usual object notation: `#<Object:0x007fae0a87ac48>`.

Comment: By the documentation to [`Module#included`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-included), it receives module or *class* object where the `Module#include` is invoked.

Comment: "main" is the special top-level Object instance and initial execution context of a Ruby program. It is also special in methods defined inside become its (private) instance methods.

Comment: Objects don't have an `include` method, only modules do.  `main` is an instance of `Object`, and `Module`is not in the ancestors.  It *must* be a special singleton method version of `include` just for `main`, right?

Comment: What is special is `main`, not `include`.

Comment: Where does the `main.include` method come from?  It's not part of the Object class...

Comment: @odigity `Object` does inherit `Module#include`, because is an instance of a `Class` superclass, which is a descendant of `Module` class, which is a subclass of `Object` - so the mutual(cyclic) dependency. In addition, for *main* object is defined on its singleton class - `self.method(:include).owner
    #<Class:#<Object:0x00000001305c68>` .

Comment: I think I just broke a synapse.

Comment: @odigity It's really not that hard. The concept of a superclass is quite common in OO languages and the cyclic relationship is a fundamental principle implemented at the core, bellow object system available to a programmer. `Class.kind_of?(Object) && Object.kind_of?(Class)    # true`. And the `Module` class lies between `Class` and `Object`, so it can inherit `include` method: `Object.respond_to? :include    # true` and `Object.method(:include).owner    # Module`. Simple and consistent.

Comment: The ruby 'top level' is kind of weird and unique, it sometimes behaves like an instance of Object and sometimes like the Object class. https://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2010/11/23/what-is-the-ruby-top-level/

Comment: If it's below the the object system, it's weird by definition.  If it wasn't weird, it could be implemented above the object system.  :)  Anyway, thanks for the help.  Maybe one of you (joanbm?) would like to repost something as an answer so it can be accepted?  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`main` is special, and has its own definition of `include`. That is, its singleton_class has its own definition of `include`. To prove it:

```
irb(main):017:0> method(:include).owner
=> #<Class:#<Object:0x007fc0398c6468>>
irb(main):018:0> self.singleton_class
=> #<Class:#<Object:0x007fc0398c6468>>
```

The `include` you're thinking of is defined on `Module`:

```
MyClass.method(:include).owner
=> Module
```

So, `include` acts different at the "top level", aka on the object we're calling `main` for the simplest possible reason: it's just a completely different method than `Module#include`.